# Parse json by Gson

Tags: java, json

My First Json Format

```
{
   object:[
     {
       name: "me",
       age: 20
     }
   ]
}
```

My second Json Format

```
{
    object:
    {
      name: "me",
      age: 20
    }
}
```

So object is sometimes jsonObject or sometimes JsonArray, how to convert it into Java Class Object using gson jar.

Comment: that isn't a valid json

Comment: Have you read anything about gson yet or are we your first stop?

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you have two different JSON representations, I would demonstrate each one here.

First let's make a basic structure which is common in both representations:

```
class A {
    public String name,
    public int age,
}
```

Now for the first JSON representation:

```
class B {
    public ArrayList<A> object;
}

// Now getting the object from Gson
Gson gson = new Gson();
B obj = gson.fromJson("you json string", B.class);
```

And, here is the conversion for the second JSON representation:

```
class C {
    public A object;
}

// Now getting the object from Gson
Gson gson = new Gson();
C obj = gson.fromJson("you json string", C.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle manually to parse your Json if your object can be JsonObject or JsonArray. Below is the code using Google's Gson library.

```
String jsonStr = "your json string ";

Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonObject jsonObj = gson.fromJson (jsonStr, JsonElement.class).getAsJsonObject();

JsonElement elem = jsonObj.get("object");

if(elem.isJsonArray()) { // Array
    List<YourClass> notelist = gson.fromJson(elem.toString(), new TypeToken<List<YourClass>>(){}.getType());
} else if(elem.isJsonObject()) { // Object
    YourClass note = gson.fromJson(elem.toString(), YourClass.class);
}
```

`YourClass` should be like

```
class YourClass {
   String name;
   int age;

   //Setters and Getters 
}
```